# MinGW vs Visual Studio 2008 output code quality

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, gcc

A few days ago I was told that recent versions of g++ produce "better" x86 code than MSVC 2008. Basically GCC with full optimization produces faster applications than MSVC with full optimizations.

While it's certainly correct to state that this, if true, depends a great deal on the application and the C++ code used (and I'm in the process of evaluating this claim for my application), I'm wondering what do others think.

**In essence, what have been your personal experiences when comparing the output of these two compilers?**

I'm asking about MinGW, but if your experience with vanilla GCC is somehow valid here, feel free to share that too.

Comment: Personally, I think you should mark this as subjective specifically BECAUSE you are asking for personal experiences (as opposed to an authoritative answer).  Community wiki might not hurt either, as a preemptive measure (and as you have run out of tags).

Comment: This kind of comparison is really hard to generalize. One compiler may do better on one benchmark, and another on another. On top of that, it all depends on who the programmer is and how hard they tried to tune it. A programmer working with a particular compiler can tweak the code to where it is nearly as fast as it can possibly get. Optimization is fine for hotspot code, but there is no substitute for careful hand-tuning in conjunction with a decent optimizing compiler. At that level, if there is a difference between compilers, it is ephemeral.

Comment: @John: CW shouldn't be used to preempt anything, and it's a mistake to use it because you don't think some question or answers deserve rep, for whatever reason. CW should be for questions that *only* elicit answers directed not at the OP, instead at the "community". Compare "what programming cartoon best fits my scenario of ...?" vs "what are good programming cartoons?" Lucas is capable of selecting an answer that helps him best for the question he asked, or he could also reword it to be more CW-directed. But you're right about subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience is compiling my C++ JPEG-LS image compression project. http://charls.codeplex.com

For me, Visual C++ was significantly faster.

I compiled it mostly with G++ on linux. After a lot of tuning, the G++ version was still about **10-15%** slower  on the same hardware (the same physical machine, dual booted as linux). That was after many hours of searching for G++ optimization options that actually helped. Just compiling with default optimizations G++ was 60% slower than Visual C++.

My project is perhaps somewhat a-typical because it is not C, but C++ and requires the compiler to do a lot of inlining. On both compilers, I enforce inlining to happen.

Also, it was offered to me as an explanation that the x86 has very few registers, and G++ was not good at allocating them.

### **Update:**

For a more thorough comparison of microsoft and gnu compilers, go to [this C compiler benchmark](http://willus.com/ccomp_benchmark2.shtml).
According to how I read these figures, the difference between Microsoft and GCC for 32 bit are on par with each other, although GCC is tested with profile guided optimization(PGO) and Microsoft isn't (there's no PGO in VS Express).

Without PGO, Microsoft is faster on 32 bit. On 64 bit, GCC is faster. Intel is still faster than either on either platform.

Comment: which G++ version did you use ?

Comment: By "default optimizations", do you mean "-O3"? Or just "default", meaning no optimizations?

Comment: With "default optimization", i mean -O3. I compiled with GCC 4.2.3. I also had to force G++ to optimize for modern CPU's by hand. I also went back to the latest figures, in the end, the difference was 10-15%, not 20%. Please don't get angry.

Comment: LOL, who's angry? :) You've given me a valid data point, and for that I thank you.

Comment: Since no one else felt inclined to post an answer and yours is helpful and informative, I'm marking it as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: Anybody done tests with newer versions of gcc?

Comment: Generally speaking "default" is -O2 opposed to -O3 as -O3 can actually be slower for some applications/hardware (due to memory/cache constraints).

Comment: In my personal tests I've always found them to be roughly the same, except when it came to `std::string` heavy code, since VC++ has SSO, and GCC doesn't.  VC++ is much faster for small strings, and GCC is slightly faster for big strings.