# Performance comparison between Windows gcc compiled & Visual Studio compiled

Tags: visual-studio, performance, gcc, cygwin, overhead

I'm currently compiling an open source optimization library (native C++) supplied with makefiles for use with gcc. As I am a Windows user, I'm curious on the two options I see of compiling this, using gcc with MinGW/Cygwin or manually building a Visual Studio project and compiling the source.

1) If I compile using MinGW/Cygwin + gcc, will the resulting .lib (static library) require any libraries from MinGW/Cygwin? I.e. can I distribute my compiled .lib to a Windows PC that doesn't have MinGW/Cygwin and will it still run?

2) Other than performance differences between the compilers themselves, is there an overhead associated when compiling using MinGW/Cygwin and gcc - as in does the emulation layer get compiled into the library, or does gcc build a native Windows library?

3) If speed is my primary objective of the library, which is the best method to use? I realise this is quite open ended, and I may be best running my own benchmarks, but if someone has experience here this would be great!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215033/mingw-vs-visual-studio-2008-output-code-quality

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of Cygwin is the Linux emulation layer, and by default (ie if you don't cross-compile), binaries need `cygwin1.dll` to run.

This is not the case for MinGW, which creates binaries as 'native' as the ones from MSVC. However, MinGW comes with its own set of runtime libraries, in particular `libstdc++-6.dll`. This library can also be linked statically by using `-static-libstdc++`, in which case you also probably want to compile with `-static-libgcc`.

This does not mean that you can freely mix C++ libraries from different compilers (see [this page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers) on mingw.org). If you do not want to restrict yourself to an `extern "C"` interface to your library, you most likely will have to choose a single compiler and stick with it.

As to your performance concerns: Using Cygwin only causes a (minor?) penalty when actually interacting with the OS - where raw computations are concerned, only the quality of the optimizer matters.